# Any way to find out top running process?

Tags: python, python-3.6

I need to get the top running process on the windows system. Is there any way to find out this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow :) Please be very specific when you ask questions on the site. In this case, since there doesn't seem to be a programming/implementation aspect to this question, you might be better off posting on [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to elaborate further your questions since it could be related to several topics in general.

Basically, through User interface you can go to windows>Windows Task Manager>click on **processes** tab and see in real time the consumption on them. By default, the Processes tab displays a list of the running processes and their actual resource utilization depending on the OS version:

```
Image Name – the binary executable file of the running process
User Name – the user of the current process
CPU – processor time utilization as a percentage of total CPU resource
Memory – physical memory utilization in Kilobytes
Disk
Network
```

To do this task through command:
-Select the start menu and type “command”
-hover the mouse over Command Prompt so it’s highlighted and then select Run as administrator on the right (You may need to select Yes on a pop-up window to approve running Command Prompt as *administrator*)
-Once the command prompt is open, type **tasklist** and press enter to see a list of processes running on your system.

As an example, in [here](https://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/save-a-list-of-running-processes-to-a-text-file-in-windows/) you will find more than one way to get the running processes on the windows system (*Windows XP*, *Windows 7*, *Windows 8*, and *Windows 10*) and then save it to a file if needed.